# Cannot import pyodbc insisde an azure function but an import in regular python file works (using the same venv in both)

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, macos, pyodbc

I have followed official tutorial for installing ODBC driver and installed pydobc with exporting the flags and  updating odbc files with drivers location. I am able to print `pyodbc.drivers()` and find them

I have a python venv where I pip installed pyodbc and with success I can

```
python3.9 -m venv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
pip install pyodbc
> installed 4.0.32
```

```
python
import pyodbc
pyodbc.drivers()  # locates and prints with a success
```

When I try to host a default code azure function it's a success. But when I add `import pyodbc` at the top of the file, it fails.

Expected behaviour:

- Function should run and import pyodbc

Actual behaviour:

- It fails, stack trace below.

Specs:

- Python: 3.9.13
- Core Tools Version 3.0.4585 Commit hash: N/A  (64-bit)
- Function Runtime Version: 3.7.1.0
- Mac os M1 12.4

```
For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2022-07-09T15:45:22.308Z] Traceback (most recent call last):
[2022-07-09T15:45:22.314Z]   File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools@3/3.0.4585/workers/python/3.9/OSX/X64/azure_functions_worker/bindings/shared_memory_data_transfer/file_accessor_unix.py", line 127, in _get_valid_mem_map_dirs
[2022-07-09T15:45:22.315Z]     os.makedirs(dir_path)
[2022-07-09T15:45:22.315Z]   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/os.py", line 215, in makedirs
[2022-07-09T15:45:22.315Z]     makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
[2022-07-09T15:45:22.315Z]   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/os.py", line 225, in makedirs
[2022-07-09T15:45:22.315Z]     mkdir(name, mode)
[2022-07-09T15:45:22.315Z] PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/dev/shm'
[2022-07-09T15:45:22.629Z] Worker process started and initialized.
[2022-07-09T15:45:23.001Z] Worker failed to function id 716b2b93-8695-4822-ad71-cd76c3035b3c.
[2022-07-09T15:45:23.006Z] Result: Failure
[2022-07-09T15:45:23.006Z] Exception: ImportError: dlopen(/Users/bartoszlachowicz/Desktop/CodeProjects/customers-slack-app/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyodbc.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_SQLAllocHandle'. Troubleshooting Guide: https://aka.ms/functions-modulenotfound
[2022-07-09T15:45:23.006Z] Stack:   File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools@3/3.0.4585/workers/python/3.9/OSX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 305, in _handle__function_load_request
[2022-07-09T15:45:23.006Z]     func = loader.load_function(
[2022-07-09T15:45:23.006Z]   File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools@3/3.0.4585/workers/python/3.9/OSX/X64/azure_functions_worker/utils/wrappers.py", line 42, in call
[2022-07-09T15:45:23.006Z]     raise extend_exception_message(e, message)
[2022-07-09T15:45:23.006Z]   File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools@3/3.0.4585/workers/python/3.9/OSX/X64/azure_functions_worker/utils/wrappers.py", line 40, in call
[2022-07-09T15:45:23.006Z]     return func(*args, **kwargs)
[2022-07-09T15:45:23.006Z]   File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools@3/3.0.4585/workers/python/3.9/OSX/X64/azure_functions_worker/loader.py", line 85, in load_function
[2022-07-09T15:45:23.006Z]     mod = importlib.import_module(fullmodname)
[2022-07-09T15:45:23.006Z]   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
[2022-07-09T15:45:23.006Z]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[2022-07-09T15:45:23.006Z]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
[2022-07-09T15:45:23.006Z]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
[2022-07-09T15:45:23.006Z]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[2022-07-09T15:45:23.006Z]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
[2022-07-09T15:45:23.006Z]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
[2022-07-09T15:45:23.006Z]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
[2022-07-09T15:45:23.006Z]   File "/Users/bartoszlachowicz/Desktop/CodeProjects/customers-slack-app/__app__/overview/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
[2022-07-09T15:45:23.006Z]     import pyodbc
[2022-07-09T15:45:23.007Z] .
```

## Update

Importing pyodbc fails when using python3.7.4 and running python file

```
import pyodbc
```

```
<ImportError: dlopen(/Users/bartoszlachowicz/Desktop/CodeProjects/new/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyodbc.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_SQLAllocHandle'
```

Comment: It could be because of missing M1 support. See: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/885

Answer (score 1):

After reproducing from our end, We also faced the same issue and noticed that the ODBC drivers were missing. Installing the ODBC Drivers made this work.

**REFERENCES:**
[Install the Microsoft ODBC driver for SQL Server (macOS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/install-microsoft-odbc-driver-sql-server-macos?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Hi Swetha!
I'm sorry butI do not understand your answer furthermore I am able to list the drivers using ```pyodbc.drivers()```

Comment: @BartekLachowicz,  as your initial ask was  'Function should run and import pyodbc', we could able to make this work after installing ODBC Drivers. Apologies if the answer wasn't clear. I have updated my answer.

Comment: When you say you managed to reproduce, what do you mean? Just to be clear: My problem is  invoking ```import pyodbc  pyodbc.drivers()``` just from venv works and it prints drivers but when I try to do that from Azure functions I get  flat namespace '_SQLAllocHandle' error

PS:
I am asking cause it seems from what you wrote that you reproduced different scenario where drivers were initially missing and then after installing it you managed to run it.

My problem is that I can use the drivers on the **venv** but when I use the same venv to host functon it fails

Comment: Also when I try to use the same setting and Python 3.7.4 I get this error even without hosting Azure function

```ImportError: dlopen(/Users/bartoszlachowicz/Desktop/CodeProjects/new/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyodbc.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_SQLAllocHandle'```